# How to check if a numpy array contains the elements of another array in the exact order theyre in in the second array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So Im iterating over rows of pixels that'll look like this

```
row = [0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0]
```

and I'll have another array called whiteLine which looks like

```
whiteLine = [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
```

And i want to check if there are 6 white pixels in a row. Or basically check if the whiteLine array explicitly exists in the row array

```py
Example

row = [0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0]
True

row = [0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0]
False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sliding_window_view` on `row` and compare the values against `whiteList` calling all at axis=1 then any sebsequently:

```py
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
>>> (sliding_window_view(row, window_shape=len(whiteLine))==whiteLine).all(axis=1).any()
True
```

Comment: Thank you this, `sliding_window_view` seems to be exactly what I need. Could you just please explain what the use of `all(axis=1).any()`, is? These functions kinda confuse me

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done via looking at the convolution between `row` and `whiteLine`, and checking to see if one gets the value of convolvin `whiteLine` with itself.
Which makes this a one-liner:

```
np.any(np.convolve(whiteLine, whiteLine, 'valid')[0] == np.convolve(whiteLine, row, 'valid'))
```

Testing with the two examples you gave produces the correct outputs, but more importantly, this is a much more general than just searching for "6 consecutive 255s"...

Answer (score -3):

a little function i wrote to maybe help you solve ur question

```
def checker(num):
    counter = 0
    Pass = False
    for i in num:
        counter += 1
        if (sum(num[counter:counter+6]) >= 1530):
            Pass = True


    return Pass        


checker(row1) #True
checker(row2) #False
```

works with both examples u gave

Comment: This is *extremely* specific to the example at hand, and very unefficient with the looping...

Comment: I appreciate the contribution but as already mentioned this is very inefficient especially in the context of numpy arrays. And having to calculate 255*6 should make you think twice about the solution

Comment: @ShlomiF
ohh thanks for correcting me but may I know why is it considered inefficient? 